# Full-text search not finding results by removing characters at the font of the string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, full-text-search

I have an full-text catalog on my table when I remove the first couple of characters of
the search string it can't find my products anymore but when I remove the last couple it
finds the right products.

When I found out I tested the behavior on a other site/server, and there it is fully working,
doesn't matter if I remove some characters at the front or back it still finds my products.

Working:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Product WHERE CONTAINS((FreeTextSearchString),'"*ij2001AR*"')
SELECT ProductId FROM Product WHERE CONTAINS((FreeTextSearchString),'"*ij2001*"')
```

Not working:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Product WHERE CONTAINS((FreeTextSearchString),'"*2001AR*"')
```

Why is it behaving like that? And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

as per my observation on [Query 7 (CONTAINS)](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sample-full-text-search-engine)

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE contains(Description,'  "*azine"  ')
```

You can't use an asterisk as a placeholder for a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at msdn for the CONTAINS Syntax it seems you should be passing the column where you are searching as the first argument:

```
DECLARE @SearchWord varchar(30)
SET @SearchWord ='performance'
SELECT Description 
FROM Production.ProductDescription 
WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @SearchWord);
```

In the example above if you were filtering the field Description for 'perf' without the * it should return the row with 'performance' on the field description, right?

Link to the msdn reference:  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187787.aspx)