# SQL Server 2012 : full-text query has results for compound word but not for compounds (separate terms)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

In my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 table I have a full-text indexed column, which contains the word 'bittersweet' many times.

Now when I execute my search query with input 'bittersweet' I get the following query and results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONTAINS((FTString),'"*bittersweet*"')
```

Gives me many results. Which is okay.

But when I input 'bitter' and 'sweet', which I translate to the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONTAINS((FTString),'"*bitter*" AND "*sweet*"')
```

Gives me 0 results, which I didn't expect.

Why is this behavior? And what should I change to get the desired result? (Which I think should be almost the same for both queries.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full-text search not finding results by removing characters at the font of the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618652/full-text-search-not-finding-results-by-removing-characters-at-the-font-of-the-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
--if words separated from each other
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   CONTAINS (FTString, 'bitter AND sweet')

--otherwise
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONTAINS(FTString,'bittersweet') 
      OR CONTAINS(FTString, 'bitter AND sweet')
```

for more information about 'contain' method use this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

[image]

Comment: The first doesn't work. The second is way too slow. Performance is why i shifted from LIKE queries to Full-Text.

Comment: @TysHTTP, this is because searched words are not separated from each other in your table filed FTString. P.S. "like" method was removed, see updated post